# ansible awx/tower not accepting list of values in a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I am trying to launch an awx/tower job template passing a list of values in a variable but the task is getting executed only on one target host.

sample request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -s -u admin:admin123 -d '{ "extra_vars": { "domain": "dom-cn-1", "targets": "dev-cn-c1", "targets": "dev-cn-c2", "fwcmd": "fw sam -v -J src 192.168.10.10" }}' -k https://172.16.102.4/api/v2/job_templates/10/launch/
```

The above command does not execute as expected and runs on a single host. However, this is working as expected when I run the same playbook via cli.

### vars file snip

```
domain: dom-cn-1
targets:
    - dev-cn-c1
    - dev-cn-c2
```

### Playbook file

```
- name: "Create output file"
  check_point_mgmt:
    command: run-script
    parameters:
      script-name: "Create output file"
      script: "fw sam -v  -J src  192.168.10.10"
      targets: "{{ targets }}"
    session-data: "{{login_response}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's extract your json in your curl command:

```
{
  "extra_vars": { 
    "domain": "dom-cn-1",
    "targets": "dev-cn-c1",
    "targets": "dev-cn-c2",
    "fwcmd": "fw sam -v -J src 192.168.10.10"
  }
}
```

You are not passing a list but twice the same parameter with different values. You have to correct you json like this:

```
{
  "extra_vars": { 
    "domain": "dom-cn-1",
    "targets": ["dev-cn-c1", "dev-cn-c2"],
    "fwcmd": "fw sam -v -J src 192.168.10.10"
  }
}
```